# Getting first and third word from string if tenth is a specific word

Tags: php

I have a constantly updated URL .txt file and I would like to grab the first and third words from every line where the tenth word is "B738". The words are spearated with ':'

Example from the file, here is 1 line: (yes, it is 1 line)

RYR98G:1374442:First Last:PILOT::36.50552:-13.87929:31183:451:B738:438:LPFR:31000:LPMA:UK1:100:1:7010:::1:I:0:0:1:41:3:30:GCXO:+VFPS+/V/PBN/A1B1C1D1S1S2 DOF/190521 REG/EIEFF OPR/RYR PER/C RMK/TCAS:N0438F310 IXOL9V IXOLI DCT LATRU DCT VERAM Q205 PECKY UQ146 EPAKA EPAK1X:0:0:0:0:::20190521084125:215:30.121:1020:

I would like to grab the "RYR98G" and the "First Last" because the tenth word is B738

```
<?php


$text = file_get_contents('http://data.vattastic.com/vatsim-data.txt');
$lines = explode("\n", $text);
$skipped_content = implode("\n", array_slice($lines, 62));

echo nl2br($skipped_content);


?>
```

Comment: I don't understand how `B738` is the tenth word.  Define what a "word" is here.

Comment: I am sorry if i wrote it inaccurately, one word is what between 2 :
So the first word is RYR98G, second is 1374442, third is First Last but I wrote that the words are separated with colons

Comment: 1. RYR98G
2. 1374442
3. First Last
4. PILOT
5. empty(none)
6. 36.50552
7. -13.87929
8. 31183
9. 451
10. B738

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should do what you want:

```
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $words = explode(':', $line);
    if (isset($words[9]) && $words[9] == 'B738') {
        echo "First: $words[0]\nThird: $words[2]\n";
    }
}
```

Output (for your sample line):

```
First: RYR98G
Third: First Last
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/EOb35)

Comment: Thanks, almost perfect. I got the datas, but I got a lots of Undefined offset error.

Comment: If you are getting offset errors then you probably don't have lines matching your example. You'll need to check the array size before returning values i.e if( count($lines)>9 && $lines[9] == "B738" ) { .... }

Comment: @Bence it may be you have some lines that don't have 10 words. I've modified the code to include a check for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$text = file_get_contents('http://data.vattastic.com/vatsim-data.txt');
$lines = explode(":", $text);
if( $lines[9] == "B738" ){
    echo $lines[0]; //RYR98G
    echo $lines[2]; //First Last
}
?>
```

Comment: It is preferred that you provide some explanation along with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Here the stript, you need to load the content of your txt, in a variable.

```
<?php 
$input_lines = "RYR98G:1374442:First Last:PILOT::36.50552:-13.87929:31183:451:B738:438:LPFR:31000:LPMA:UK1:100:1:7010:::1:I:0:0:1:41:3:30:GCXO:+VFPS+/V/PBN/A1B1C1D1S1S2 DOF/190521 REG/EIEFF OPR/RYR PER/C RMK/TCAS:N0438F310 IXOL9V IXOLI DCT LATRU DCT VERAM Q205 PECKY UQ146 EPAKA EPAK1X:0:0:0:0:::20190521084125:215:30.121:1020:"; // example of line

$matches = array(); //Array 
$search = preg_match_all('/(.*?):(.*?)/im', $input_lines, $matches); //regex matching

if($matches[1][9] == "B738") //target :)
{
  print_r('B738 Found! <br />');
  print_r('Item 1!'.$matches[1][0].'<br />');
  print_r('Item 2!'.$matches[1][3].'<br />');
}

// Debug of your array. As you can see all items matched.
foreach ($matches[1] as $match) {
  echo " Item: ".$i."<br />";
    echo $match;
  $i++;

}
```